# Finding equation of tangent plane surface from vector curves on the surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I need to find the equation of the tangent plane to a surface $S$ at point $P(4, 1, 3)$. I have the information both of these curves lie on $S$: $$r_1(t) = \vec(4+3t,1-t^2,3-5t+t^2)$$$$r_2(u)=\vec(3+u^2,2u^3-1,2u+1)$$From googling I've been able to do the following and get the correct answer:$$r_1'(t)=\vec(3,-2t,2t-5)$$$$r_1'(0)=\vec(3,0,-5)$$$$r_2'(u)=\vec(2u,6u^2,2)$$$$r_2'(1)=\vec(2,6,2)$$$$r_1'(0) \times r_2'(1)=(30,-16,18)$$
equation of tangent plane:
$$30(x-4)-16(y-1)+18(z-3)=0$$

by substituting the cross product of $r_1'(0)$ and $r_2'(1)$ and $P(4,1,3)$. My question is how am I supposed to know how to use $t=0$ and $u=1$? From the comment I figured out it’s something to do with parameter using but I still don’t understand how I know what $t$ and $u$ are.

Comment: You have to use $P$ somewhere when you use the parametrizations.

Comment: I'm not understanding how the parameterizations work I think? The stops between finding the derivative and cross multiplying the equations I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: For what value of $t$ does $\vec r_1(t)=(4,1,3)$? For what value of $u$ does $\vec r_2(u)=(4,1,3)$?